# How can I implement this type of logic using Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bluebird

I am fairly new to the world of Javascript promises and am having issues implementing the following:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var jenkinsapi = require('jenkins-api');
var asyncJenkinsAPI = Promise.promisifyAll(jenkinsapi);
var jenkins = asyncJenkinsAPI.init("http://<user>:<password>@localhost:8080");

app.get('/api/servers', function(req, resp) {
    SavedJob.find({})
        .then(function(jobs) {
            return Promise.all(jobs.map(function(job){
                // do two calls with each job.name
                // build new data with the result of the two calls
                // return new data to next part of chain
                var job_status = jenkins.job_info(job.name, function(err, jobData) { return jobData; });
                var build_info = jenkins.last_build_info(job.name, function(err, buildData) { return buildData; });
                return {task_name: job_status.name,
                        status: STATUSMAP[job_status.color] || "UNKNOWN",
                        latest_build:
                            {
                                build_date: build_info.timestamp,
                                build_status: build_info.result,
                                build_number: build_info.number,
                                build_url: build_info.url
                            }
                        };
            }));
        })
        .then(function(results){
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
```

How can I best implement making two asynchronous calls inside the `Promise.all()` with each `job.name` and have the set of results at the end?

Comment: That's exactly how it works. I'm not sure what you are asking about. Just return a promise from the `map` callback.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: [Promisify](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) those callback-taking functions.

Comment: I think I am missing a crucial piece, when I do `Promise.promisifyAll(require('jenkins-api'))` I still get undefined values when logging to console.

Comment: Can you update your question to show what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121271/discussion-between-muttonchop-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having promisified jenkins, you will need to use the new promise-returning methods:

```
var job_promise = jenkins.job_infoAsync(job.name);
var build_promise = jenkins.last_build_infoAsync(job.name);
```

(you might want to pass `{suffix: "_async"}` as an [option to `promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) for nicer method names).

Then combine those two promises (`Promise.all`/`Promise.props`/`Promise.join`):

```
return Promise.join(job_promise, build_promise, function(job_status, build_info) {
    return {
        task_name: job_status.name,
        status: STATUSMAP[job_status.color] || "UNKNOWN",
        latest_build: {
            build_date: build_info.timestamp,
            build_status: build_info.result,
            build_number: build_info.number,
            build_url: build_info.url
        }
    };
});
```

The rest of your code (mapping, chaining) is working fine.

Comment: After putting your solution into the code, I am getting that `name` is undefined. Also, using `Async` (and trying putting in `_async` into promisify) suffix returns an error saying they are not functions.

Comment: Which name is undefined? The property? Is that an error?

Comment: Yes, if you pass the suffix you'd have to use `.job_info_async(…)` and `.last_build_info_async(…)` of course instead of the default `Async` suffix

Comment: `var asyncJenkinsAPI = Promise.promisifyAll(jenkinsapi);` and using `.job_infoAsync(…)` throws an TypeError saying it is not a function.

Comment: That's weird, it should work. Maybe try `asyncJenkinsAPI.job_…`, otherwise open a bug with Bluebird.

Comment: Regarding `job_status`, it doesn't throw an error about `name` being undefined, rather about accessing a `.name` property on `undefined`. I messed up the paramter name. But still, this is very weird, code evaluation should not even get till there if `job_infoAsync(…)` already threw.

Comment: The solution to this ended up `promisify`-ing the individual call in the jenkins api.

Comment: @Muttonchop Glad you found a solution :-) If my answer was helpful, please accept it. And file a bug with Bluebird that `promisifyAll` doesn't work for `jenkins-api`.